# Topic challenges to promote the site

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, topic-challenges

I came across [Worldbuilding's fortnightly topic challenges](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges) recently. It's based on [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work) on meta SE about topic challenges. I think this could be a nice way to promote our site by challenging on the one hand existing members to ask questions in said topic and on the other hand having quite focused topics to advertise on other sites and in interested communities.

It also gives a sneaking excuse to mention our site on a recurring basis on meta SE. That can certainly not hurt. So first, I am calling for vehement opposition to be voiced now or forever hold your peace. Secondly I am calling for topic suggestions.

Please suggest single topics per answer.

*"Tag lines"* as well as possible promotion targets (i.e. communities that might be interested in those challenges) for those suggestions can gladly be suggested in the comments of the answers.

---

#### *Internet of Things Topic Challenges*

> [**Internet of Things Topic Challenge #1 - Keeping my gadget data private**](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231/biweekly-internet-of-things-topic-challenge-1) 
>  Questions about the privacy and data security on IoT gadgets, e.g. wearables and health gadgets.
>
> [**Internet of Things Topic Challenge #2 - New types of sensor nodes**](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248/biweekly-internet-of-things-topic-challenge-2) 
>  
>   Questions about new and emerging endpoint technology.
>
> [**Internet of Things Topic Challenge #3 - Build your own hardware to run Alexa Voice Service**](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259/biweekly-internet-of-things-topic-challenge-3) 
>  
>   Use the Alexa Voice Service (AVS) to add intelligent voice control to any connected product that has a microphone and speaker.

<sub><sub>I'll also update the list in [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290164/338924) to the post on meta Stack Exchange.</sub></sub>

---

*Current front runner for next challenge:*

> Build your own hardware to run Alexa Voice Service
>
> [Voice-Enable Your Product with Alexa](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges)

(by Bence Kaulics)

---

Answer (score 5):

> New types of sensor nodes

This is a more challenging area to ask questions about, but I'm thinking about emerging endpoint technology, multiple sensors and processing combined.

**Selected for [Challenge #2](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248) (8<sup>th</sup> Feburary to 22<sup>nd</sup> February)**.

Comment: I think a few *quality* questions about the technical side of IoT would be great; we get quite a lot of broad ones at the minute and a topic challenge could help to create some good examples.

Answer (score 4):

> Keeping my gadget data private

Questions about the privacy and data security on IoT gadgets, e.g. wearables and health gadgets.

**Selected for [Challenge #1](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231/biweekly-internet-of-things-topic-challenge-1) (24<sup>th</sup> January to 7<sup>th</sup> Feburary)**.

Answer (score 4):

> The Alexa FAQ Amazon did not provide

We have Alexa already as a highly attractive topic for questions there is still more stuff about Alexa to ask that cannot be easily found in Amazon's FAQ.

Comment: This can also be varied for other popular devices e.g. the Google Home.

Answer (score 4):

> Build your own hardware to run Alexa Voice Service

[Voice-Enable Your Product with Alexa](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-voice-service)

"Use the Alexa Voice Service (AVS) to add intelligent voice control to any connected product that has a microphone and speaker."

Answer (score 3):

> Security flaws in and around voice assistants

Existance and avoiding security flaws in voice assistants, e.g. 
[How can I securely support unlocking my door through Google Home?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/838/how-can-i-securely-support-unlocking-my-door-through-google-home)

Answer (score 3):

> Steampunk IoT

Need I explain?

---

<sup><sub>Maybe this is a suggestion not to be taken too seriously.</sub></sup>

Comment: We should give some other topics a chance first. Let's plan this for 10 weeks from now.