# Biweekly Internet of Things Topic Challenge #1

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, topic-challenges

After quite nice reception of the idea to have [topic challenges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work) for [our site](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224/lets-start-topic-challenges-to-promote-the-site) we are about to start the first one. I allowed myself to pick the one that seems a bit more easily accessible and promotable from the top-most voted ideas.

Biweekly topic challenge #1, January 24<sup>th</sup> - February 7<sup>th</sup>

> **Keeping my gadget data private**

Additional we plan to have an event in chat on January 24<sup>th</sup>, 18:00 GMT—[Topic Challenge #1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/49682/chat-of-things?tab=schedule)—to kick off the challenge, gather more opinions and ideas on the challenge and get some starting buzz going.

This topic doesn't seem to need an extra tag, but remember to tag every challenge question with [privacy](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privacy) and likely a tag for the gadget in question.

---

Why am I posting this so far in advance? Since we haven't got any pro-tems yet we need the help of the CMs to get the chat event and this post *featured*. Which I hope they will support us with. On Monday I'll also add an answer to the Meta SE question about topic challenges and I'd like to have our end setup by then. It also gives everyone a moment to prepare a bit, so hopefully we can start with a few privacy questions on Tuesday *right away* (tm).

It also allows all of you who might have ideas about where to promote us especially on the topic of privacy to prepare a bit more and maybe pull some experts in starting Tuesday.

So let's do this!

Comment: If anyone is interested, here is a [chat event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/49682/chat-of-things?tab=schedule).

Answer (score 4):

### Results

**8 new questions** were posted! **87.5%** of the questions posted for the event (7/8) were answered, and some got multiple answers.

### Questions Posted

<sup>(newest first)</sup>

- [Will Home Assistant's face recognition data be stored permanently in the cloud?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/921/will-home-assistants-face-recognition-data-be-stored-permanently-in-the-cloud)
- [Will changing my user name and password block Mirai attacks?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/911/49)
- [Is the Nest Cam recording even when "switched off"?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/906/is-the-nest-cam-recording-even-when-switched-off)
- [Should I use a different password on each IoT device?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/885/49)
- [How do I stop the Fitbit Surge from storing GPS data?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/875/how-do-i-stop-the-fitbit-surge-from-recording-gps-data)
- [How can I set up IP whitelisting on an IP camera without support for whitelists?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/873/how-to-add-ip-whitelisting-functionality-to-an-ip-camera-which-does-not-support)
- [Are Samsung's "S Health" devices storing health data in the cloud?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/868/are-samsungs-s-health-devices-storing-health-data-in-the-cloud)
- [What personal information is stored on my Amazon Echo?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/869/what-personal-information-is-stored-on-my-amazon-echo)

---

So we can track how effective the topic challenges are, add any questions you post for the challenge here. Simply copy the following template into the list above with your questions:

```
- https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/357/is-the-amazon-echo-always-listening-and-sending-data-to-the-cloud
```

This is automatically converted to the following by the editor:

- [Is the Amazon Echo 'always listening' and sending data to the cloud?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/357/is-the-amazon-echo-always-listening-and-sending-data-to-the-cloud)

Simply **edit this post to add your questions** (100 reputation points are required). If you are unable to do this, simply comment on your question and someone should add it here for you.

Comment: Let me borrow the structure of the answer. ^^