# Biweekly Internet of Things Topic Challenge #2

Tags: discussion, topic-challenges

After a quite nice reception of the idea to have [topic challenges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work) for [our site](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224/lets-start-topic-challenges-to-promote-the-site) we are about to start the second. It's the second one of the top-most voted challenge ideas. And it starts now and will also run for two weeks.

Biweekly topic challenge #2, February 7<sup>th</sup> - February 21<sup>st</sup>

> **New types of sensor nodes** 
>   Questions about new and emerging endpoint technology.

(suggested by Sean Houlihane)

Additionally there is a little chat gathering, tomorrow, February 8<sup>th</sup>, 18:00 GMT—[Topic Challenge #2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/49682/chat-of-things?tab=schedule)—to kick off the challenge, gather more opinions and ideas on the challenge and get some starting buzz going by finding some places to promote questions of the sort.

This topic doesn't seem to need an extra tag, but remember to tag every challenge question with [sensors](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensors).

Let the challenge begin!

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple of links that cover some of the more general background ideas:

[Self-powered wireless nodes](http://www.batterypoweronline.com/main/articles/five-building-blocks-of-self-powered-wireless-sensor-nodes/)

[General ideas on fused sensor sources](http://www.plextek.com/blog/sensor-systems-getting-to-market-quickly/) and a design-house's definition of [smart sensors](http://www.plextek.com/markets/smartsensors/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing these sources, "Self-powered wireless nodes" was especially a good reading.

Answer (score 3):

### Questions Posted

<sup>(newest first)</sup>

- [Why might data be sent to a cloud service when it could be processed on the edge?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1090/why-might-data-be-sent-to-a-cloud-service-when-it-could-be-processed-on-the-edge)
- [Where can I harvest energy in my home to power my wireless sensors?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1040/where-can-i-harvest-energy-in-my-home-to-power-my-wireless-sensors)

---

So we can track how effective the topic challenges are, add any questions you post for the challenge here. Simply copy the following template into the list above with your questions:

```
- https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1040/where-can-i-harvest-energy-in-my-home-to-power-my-wireless-sensors
```

This is automatically converted to the following by the editor:

- [Where can I harvest energy in my home to power my wireless sensors?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1040/where-can-i-harvest-energy-in-my-home-to-power-my-wireless-sensors)

Simply **edit this post to add your questions**.