# Biweekly Internet of Things Topic Challenge #3

Tags: discussion, topic-challenges

After a quite nice reception of the idea to have [topic challenges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work) for [our site](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224/lets-start-topic-challenges-to-promote-the-site) we are about to start the second. It's the second one of the top-most voted challenge ideas. And it starts now and will also run for two weeks.

---

Biweekly topic challenge #3, February 21<sup>th</sup> - March 7<sup>th</sup>

> **Build your own hardware to run Alexa Voice Service** and **The Alexa FAQ Amazon did not provide**

(suggested by Bence Kaulics and Helmar)

---

This topic doesn't seem to need an extra tag, but remember to tag every challenge question with relevant tags, such as [alexa](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alexa), [hardware](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) and [sensors](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensors).

Let the challenge begin!

Comment: Starting point: [Voice-enable your product with Alexa](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-voice-service).

Answer (score 2):

### Questions Posted

<sup>(oldest first)</sup>

- [Does Amazon provide any free wake word engines for use with the Alexa Voice Service?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/does-amazon-provide-any-free-wake-word-engines-for-use-with-the-alexa-voice-serv)
- [Keep Alexa from responding when I'm talking in my sleep](https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/1164/49)
- [IFTTT recipe on single Echo Dot](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/ifttt-recipe-on-single-echo-dot)

---

So we can track how effective the topic challenges are, add any questions you post for the challenge here. Simply copy the following template into the list above with your questions:

```
- https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/357/is-the-amazon-echo-always-listening-and-sending-data-to-the-cloud
```

This is automatically converted to the following by the editor:

- [Is the Amazon Echo 'always listening' and sending data to the cloud?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/357/is-the-amazon-echo-always-listening-and-sending-data-to-the-cloud)

Simply **edit this post to add your questions** (100 reputation points are required). If you are unable to do this, simply comment on your question and someone should add it here for you.